# How to make the values of one column the main column names using spread()

Tags: r, dplyr, spread

I need to run a chi-square test so I need the levels of one column (gender) to be the column names for the output of different variables. Here's some data:

```
test <- data.frame(gender = as.character(sample(c('male','female'),10, replace = T)),
           test1 = sample(c(1:10)),
           test2 = sample(1:5,10 , replace = T))
> test
   gender test1 test2
1  female     2     2
2    male     9     1
3    male     4     4
4  female     8     1
5  female     5     4
6  female     3     3
7  female     7     3
8  female     1     1
9    male    10     2
10   male     6     2
```

I've used the following line of code with dplyr::spread() but it's giving me an error:

```
test %>% spread(gender,test1)
Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
```

I've followed all the examples that dplyr provides using gather() and spread() but nothing is working. If you have any tips please let me know. Here's my desired outcome:

```
> goal
  male female
1   10      3
2    1      4
3    5     10
4    3      9
5    6      7
```

Comment: your example. shows test1 to have female 1 and not male as 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a sequence column grouped by gender to make a unique identifier and then use `spread

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
test %>% 
    select(-test2) %>% 
    group_by(gender) %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
    spread(gender, test1)
```